# Move most recently modified file

Tags: bash, find, xargs

I am trying to move the most recently modified file in "Pictures/". This is what I've tried:

```
find Pictures/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin -60 -print0|tail -1| xargs -0 -I {} mv "{}" Dropbox/somefolder/
```

This doesn't work and it isn't the ideal solution since I'm guessing that the file has been modified in the last hour.

I get this error:

```
mv: cannot stat 'Pictures/file.jpg' : No such file or directory
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are on GNU Linux? Or OS X, BSD, or,… ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `-print0`, `tail` won't work because your output does not contain newlines (unless your file paths do, for some unlikely reason).

Assuming that the files don't contain a newline in their path, using GNU `find`, `sort` and `xargs`:

```
find ~/Pictures -type f -printf '%T@ %P\n' | \
sort -k 1nr | sed 's/^[^ ]* //' | head -n 1 |  xargs -I {} mv "{}" ~/Dropbox
```

---

If you have Zsh, it's quite simple – again, no newlines allowed though:

```
mv -- "$(print -l **/*(.om) | head -n 1)" ~/Dropbox
```

Here, `**/*` is a recursive glob, and inside the parentheses are [qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers):

- `.` – a regular file
- `o` – sort files
- `m` – by modification time

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, as long as you never need to find hidden files.

```
cd /path/to/Pictures
mv "`ls -ltr | grep -v ^d | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut  -d ' ' -f9-`" /path/to/dropbox
```

Comment: This fails if files contain whitespace in their name. [Never parse `ls` output.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Good point. Changed the cut from -f9 to -f9- and added double quotes. There's probably more reasons not to parse ls that I don't know about, but at least this catches whitespace in filenames, and maybe some other special characters.

Comment: Heh. It gets trickier (that's why parsing `ls` really isn't recommended): What if the file contains two spaces? Then it wouldn't be found by `mv` because you got rid of the consecutive spaces with `tr`. Not that this is so likely, but you never know.

Comment: Agreed. Your solution is much better. I couldn't think of a way to sort files from find by date.